# Grep, Sed... Awk to modify lines in a file

Tags: string, shell, replace, sed, grep

I've searched for this but I didn't find exactly what I'm looking for.

What I want to do is replace in the same file all the lines that contains a jar file with "PATTERN" text in the name so that I can add in those lines a new property with the sourcecode for those jar files. The sourcecode for those jars will be always in same relative folder (i.e. path1/lib/a.jar -> path1/src/java)

An example of this. This is my original file:

```
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/Search/I18N/lib/MOM-Search-I18N-0.23-ECI.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/DAS/lib/axis-1.4.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/REST/lib/org.json.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/StoreFront/lib/MOM-Search-I18N-Index-0.23-ECI.jar" />
```

And I want to get this:

```
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/Search/I18N/lib/MOM-Search-I18N-0.23-ECI.jar" sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/Search/I18N/src/main/java" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/DAS/lib/axis-1.4.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/REST/lib/org.json.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/StoreFront/lib/MOM-Search-I18N-Index-0.23-ECI.jar" sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/StoreFront/src/main/java"/>
```

I need to add a sourcepath attribute to the lines with my pattern and that sourcepath value should take the root of the path value.

As

```
grep -o 'path="[/-.0-9A-Za-z]*/lib/MOM[-.0-9A-Za-z]*.jar"' test.txt
```

gives me the lines that contain lines with the jars I'm looking for, I thought that this would solve my problem:

```
cat test.txt | sed -r 's|path="[/-.0-9A-Za-z]*/lib/MOM[-.0-9A-Za-z]*.jar"|\1 sourcepath="\2/main/src/main/java"/>|'
```

But gives me this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 91: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Any idea?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say:

```
sed 's| \(path=.*\)\(/lib\)\(/MOM[^ ]*\)| \1\2\3 source\1/src/main/java"|' inputfile
```

For your sample input, it'd produce:

```
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/Search/I18N/lib/MOM-Search-I18N-0.23-ECI.jar" sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/Search/I18N/src/main/java" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/DAS/lib/axis-1.4.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/REST/lib/org.json.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/StoreFront/lib/MOM-Search-I18N-Index-0.23-ECI.jar" sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/Momentum/StoreFront/src/main/java" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`'s basic search-replace functionality:

```
sed 's|\(PATTERN[^ ]*\)|\1 sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path1/src/main/java"|'
```

Answer (score 0):

`$ cat injars.txt | sed -r 's%(^.* path="(.*)/lib/PATTERN-.*)/>%\1 sourcepath="\2/src/main/java"/>%'`

Gives:

```
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path1/lib/jar1.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path1/lib/PATTERN-jar1.jar"  sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path1/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path2/lib/jar2.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path2/lib/PATTERN-jar2.jar"  sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path2/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path3/lib/PATTERN-jar3.jar"  sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path3/src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path3/lib/jar3.jar" />
<classpathentry path="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path4/lib/PATTERN-jar4.jar"  sourcepath="/sde/ATG/ATG10.1.2/path4/src/main/java"/>
```

for injars.txt containing your input.

Comment: Thanks jkbkot, the issue is that the path is hardcoded and could be different depending on the jar file. So the sourcepath folder should take the path attribute folder, go back one level and add /main/java

Comment: Sorry, I truncated my own message... So I need to extract the absolute path which is in "path" attribute, manipulate it to transform it into the sourcepath value and add it next to path attribute.

Comment: that's no problem. I wrote the command quickly, it can be simplified and works as you want - see my edit.

Comment: you may need to tweak the regex more for more diverse inputs.

Comment: I'm getting error messages like "invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS" ¿Any idea?

Comment: it doesn't work even on your sample input? Which OS / sed version are you using? You could get this kind of error message for example if you used plain sed instead of sed -r

Comment: try \\( and \\)instead of ( and )

Comment: well, you were using backreferences without actually defining any groups. The command works as I wrote it but you have to use it as a whole not just a part :)